# How build a list in python from a text using a regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have the following bunch of text:

```
text = """SECTION 1. CHAPTER 1. Chapter title. Art. 1.- Lorem ipsum, blah, blah. Art 2.- More meaningless text. Art 3.- A little more text. CHAPTER 2. Another chapter. Art 4.- Lorem ipsum blah, blah, blah. Art. 5.- It's getting boring. SECTION 2. CHAPTER 1. Another chapter in another section. Art. 6.- The last text. SECTION 3. CHAPTER 1. Another chapter in another section. Art. 6.- The last text. SECTION 4. CHAPTER 1. Another chapter in another section. Art. 6.- The last text."""
```

I want to split it as follows:

```
RE = r'(SECTION.*?SECTION)'
m = re.findall(RE, text, re.DOTALL)
sections = []
if m:
   for match in m:
        sections.append(match)
```

hoping that it will result in a list with 4 elements, but I ended up with only 2 elements.

```
['SECTION 1. .....', 'SECTION 3. .....']  # only showing the first letters of each element
```

Afterwards, I would like do the same for `chapters` and `articles`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm.. you only have two matches for that regex in your input. Note that your matches must start AND end with 'SECTION'

Comment: @schwobaseggl your suggestion only returns `[SECTION, SECTION, SECTION, SECTION]}`

Comment: I just saw it myself. It is not trivial!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have with your regex is that you consume the second `SECTION`. Once the first `SECTION` is found, the lazy dot matching construct consumes as few characters as possible up to the next `SECTION`, and the match returned contains the two words and all in between. Thus, having 4 `SECTION`s, you can only get two matches.

This can be solved with a regex two ways (see [demo of all 3 regexps below at IDEONE](http://ideone.com/J2gY8y)).

1. Lazy dot matching with a lookahead (less efficient, not recommended)

   `print(re.findall(r"SECTION.*?(?=$|SECTION)", text, re.DOTALL))`

When the regex engine finds the first `SECTION`  it starts consuming characters checking for the end of string (`$`) or leftmost `SECTION`.

2. Unroll-the-loop method to replace the lazy quantifier (much more efficient, requires no `DOTALL` modifier to match newline symbols)

   `print(re.findall(r"SECTION[^S]*(?:S(?!ECTION)[^S]*)*", text))`

Here, no lazy quantifier or lookahead with alternatives are necessary since the `SECTION` consumes the first `SECTION` substring, and then `[^S]*(?:S(?!ECTION)[^S]*)*` matches any substring that is not equal to `SECTION` (up to the next `SECTION` if present, or just anything else up to the end of string).

A safer similar expression that makes sure there is whitespace and digits followed by a dot after `SECTION`:

```
print(re.findall(r"SECTION\s+\d+\.[^S]*(?:S(?!ECTION\s+\d+\.)[^S]*)*", text))
```

A regex explanation:

- `SECTION` - matches `SECTION` literally
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\.` - literal dot
- `[^S]*` - any character but `S`
- `(?:S(?!ECTION\s+\d+\.)[^S]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of....

  - `S(?!ECTION\s+\d+\.)` - `S` that is not followed by `ECTION` + 1 or more whitespaces + 1 or more digits + a dot
  - `[^S]*` - any character but `S`

*UPDATE*

To obtain a dictionary in the form of `{'SECTION 1' : '...', 'SECTION 2' : '...'}`, you need to add 2 capturing groups around the key and value patterns, and then use the `dict` command. This works because [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns tuples of captured texts if capturing groups (i.e. parentheses) are specified in the regex pattern (*If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.*):

```
print(dict(re.findall(r"(SECTION\s+\d+)\.\s*([^S]*(?:S(?!ECTION\s+\d+\.)[^S]*)‌​*)", text)))
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ZAwa2m)

Comment: This is very elegant, indeed!

Comment: Just one question, what if I want in a dictionary instead? I mean: `{'SECTION 1' : '.....', 'SECTION 2' : '.....'}? Is it possible?

Comment: Add capturing groups around the key-values, and use `dict`: [`print(dict(re.findall(r"(SECTION\s+\d+)\.\s*([^S]*(?:S(?!ECTION\s+\d+\.)[^S]*)*)", text)))`](http://ideone.com/ZAwa2m).

Comment: Could you explain, why this last instruction works? Why the `re.findall` returns a list, and now returns a key-vaue?

Comment: Oh! I see! You put a parenthesis...Neat!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the word `SECTION` only appears when there is a new "section" in your string, you can always use the default `.split` method, which is way easier than using regexps.

Here's an example:

```
text = """SECTION 1. CHAPTER 1. Chapter title. Art. 1.- Lorem ipsum, blah, blah. Art 2.- More meaningless text. Art 3.- A little more text. CHAPTER 2. Another chapter. Art 4.- Lorem ipsum blah, blah, blah. Art. 5.- It's getting boring. SECTION 2. CHAPTER 1. Another chapter in another section. Art. 6.- The last text. SECTION 3. CHAPTER 1. Another chapter in another section. Art. 6.- The last text. SECTION 4. CHAPTER 1. Another chapter in another section. Art. 6.- The last text."""

delimiter = 'SECTION'
sections = [delimiter + s for s in text.split(delimiter)[1:]]
```

The result will be:

```
>>> sections
['SECTION 1. ...', 'SECTION 2. ...', 'SECTION 3. ...', 'SECTION 4. ...']
```